# Dynamic change of localization file in swift

Tags: swift, localization

I use the German language in my app and there are two types of addressing a person "Du" and "Sie". I would like to add another localizable file to my project where "Du" will be used. Basically, I would like to know if it is somehow possible to check that the German language and "Du" addressin is chosen and if it is, to use the "Du" localization file? Now only the "Sie" file exists in the project and localization is taken from it.

Comment: why not create .strings file and add localisation for other language and in App delgate use getLanguage function to get language of device and set required language according to that

Comment: Sure! The question is how to do that?
Locale.currentLahguage is { get } only propperty. 
It would be nice if you can share a code snippet for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for this issue described here: [Forcing iOS localization at runtime](https://medium.com/swift2go/forcing-ios-localization-at-runtime-the-right-way-8afa0569162a). However, the main point is that `Bundle.swizzleLocalization()` **should be called** in the `main.swift` file.

```
if Locale.current.languageCode == "de" {
     let appConfig = ApplicationConfiguration()
     if appConfig.germanLanguageType == "du" {
         Bundle.swizzleLocalization()
     }
 }
```

Thus, in the main.swift file I check the device's preferred language and if it is German, I check my `appConfig.swift` file, where specified whether "du" or "sie" addressing should be used in the app if it is "du" I call `Bundle.swizzleLocalization()`

In the extension to Bundle, I just swizzle the path to the localized file that should be used (previously added in the project)

```
extension Bundle {

    static func swizzleLocalization() {
        let orginalSelector = #selector(localizedString(forKey:value:table:))
        guard let orginalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, orginalSelector) else { return }
        
        let mySelector = #selector(myLocaLizedString(forKey:value:table:))
        guard let myMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, mySelector) else { return }
        
        if class_addMethod(self, orginalSelector, method_getImplementation(myMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(myMethod)) {
            class_replaceMethod(self, mySelector, method_getImplementation(orginalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(orginalMethod))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(orginalMethod, myMethod)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func myLocaLizedString(forKey key: String,value: String?, table: String?) -> String {
        guard let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "de-DE", ofType: "lproj"),
              let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath) else {
                  return Bundle.main.myLocaLizedString(forKey: key, value: value, table: table)
              }
        return bundle.myLocaLizedString(forKey: key, value: value, table: table)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution for SwiftUI? it doesn't seem to work